# Example of a nonprincipal incomplete ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

I am trying to build my intuition on ultrafilters by finding examples of non-implications between these properties:

- ultra
- nonprincipal
- completeness

Any filter (on a regular cardinal $\kappa$) generated by a singleton will be an ultrafilter that's $\kappa$-complete. And the club filter on $\kappa$ is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete filter that's not an ultrafilter. So my question is: are there examples of ultrafilters on some $\kappa$ that are nonprincipal, but not $\kappa$-complete? I understand that if $\kappa$ is not a measurable cardinal, then every nonprincipal ultrafilter on it is not $\kappa$-complete. But I wonder if there are more concrete examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that an incomplete filter cannot be extended to a complete ultrafilter:

If $F$ is a filter and $A_\alpha$ is a sequence of sets in $F$ for $\alpha<\gamma$, such that the intersection of the $A_\alpha$'s is "practically empty" (read: its complement is in $F$), then any ultrafilter extending $F$ will contain the complement of $\bigcap A_\alpha$, and is therefore incomplete.

Now, pick your favourite partition of $\kappa$ into countably many infinite sets, $X_n$, and let $A_n=\kappa\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}X_k$. Now consider the filter generated by $A_n$.

(Fun exercise: any filter that does not contain finite sets can be extended to a $\sigma$-incomplete ultrafilter.)

Comment: Note to the OP that this is a strong form of incompleteness: not just that the filter isn't closed under the appropriate intersections, but that such an intersection's *complement* is in the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Given the subjectivity of the term "concrete" it's difficult to give a convincing negative answer, but here's some good evidence: $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent with "There is no nonprincipal ultrafilter on any set whatsoever." Certain models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ may have definable nonprincipal ultrafilters (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155237/in-l-does-there-exist-a-definable-non-principal-ultrafilter-on-mathbbn)), but even these won't be very concrete since the relevant definitions will be quite complicated.

Note that this applies to complete and incomplete ultrafilters alike. Interestingly, *models associated to* certain types of ultrafilter can be far more concrete than any specific ultrafilter of that type: e.g. if $U_1,U_2$ are measures on the same cardinal $\kappa$ then $L[U_1]=L[U_2]$, so "$L$ with a single measurable is canonical." *(See Theorem $20.10$ in Kanamori. Note that $U$ and $W$ there are assumed to be **normal** in their respective models. This is part of Kanamori's definition of "$M$-ultrafilter," which differs from Kunen's and threw me off at first since in the absence of a normality assumption part of the conclusion of that theorem is blatantly false.)*

Comment: Really? $L[U]$ doesn't depend on the measure? That sounds suspect to me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Theorem $20.10$ in Kanamori! (Note that Kanamori says "$U=W$" as part of the conclusion, but $U$ and $W$ there are assumed to be *normal* in their respective models; this is part of his definition of "$M$-ultrafilter," which is different from Kunen's. This threw me off at first.)

Comment: That's just bizarre.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, right? I've added a bit about this to the answer.